# Reestructurado de carpetas en S3

Tags: python, aws, lambda, amazon-s3

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo muchas cuentas que tienen habilitado el logging en s3 de muchos servicios en aws, la idea es enviar los logs de cada cuenta a un bucket centralizado en la cuanta LogArchive, pero el cliente necesita poder distinguir la cuenta a la que pertenece cada carpeta, y expresó que no le sirve la estructura de carpetas actual "BucketName/AWSLogs/123456789012/" y le gustaria que cambiara a "BucketName/Log Type/Nombre de la cuenta"

por lo que intenté crear una funcion lambda que copie todos los objetos de la estructura de carpetas y renombre todas las carpetas con un numero de cuenta a su nombre asignado

```
import boto3
import re
from queue import Queue

# Definir la función lambda
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Mapeo de Account IDs a nombres de cuentas
    account_names = {
        "123456789012": "Cuenta1",
        "123456789012": "Cuenta2",
        "123456789012": "Cuenta3",
        "123456789012": "Cuenta4",
        # Agregar cuentas aquí
    }
    
    # Nombre del bucket de origen
    source_bucket = "bucket-de-origen"
    
    # Nombre del bucket de destino
    destination_bucket = "bucket-destino"
    
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
    print("Iniciando función lambda")
    
    copy_objects_recursive(s3, source_bucket, destination_bucket, account_names)

def copy_objects_recursive(s3_client, source_bucket, dest_bucket, account_names):
    objects = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=source_bucket)
    
    for obj in objects.get('Contents', []):
        obj_key = obj['Key']
        print(f"Contenido de obj: {obj_key}")
        
        account_id_match = re.search(r'/(\d+)/', obj_key)
        
        if account_id_match:
            account_id = account_id_match.group(1)
            print(f"Account ID: {account_id}")
            
            if account_id in account_names:
                account_name = account_names[account_id]
                print(f"Nombre de cuenta asociado: {account_name}")
                
                new_obj_key = re.sub(rf'/{account_id}/', f'/{account_name.replace(" ", "-").lower()}/', obj_key)
                
                if not object_copied(s3_client, dest_bucket, new_obj_key):
                    # Copiar el objeto al bucket de destino con la nueva clave
                    copy_object(s3_client, source_bucket, dest_bucket, obj_key, new_obj_key)
                else:
                    print("Objeto ya copiado previamente, omitiendo...")
            else:
                print("Account ID no encontrado en el mapeo")
        
        else:
            print("Account ID no encontrado en la clave del objeto")
    
    queue = Queue()
    
    queue.put('')
    
    while not queue.empty():
        subfolder_key = queue.get()
        
        subfolder_objects = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=source_bucket, Prefix=subfolder_key)
        
        for obj in subfolder_objects.get('Contents', []):
            sub_subfolder_key = obj['Key']
            print(f"Procesando subcarpeta: {sub_subfolder_key}")
            copy_objects_recursive(s3_client, source_bucket, dest_bucket, account_names)
            queue.put(sub_subfolder_key)

def copy_object(s3_client, source_bucket, dest_bucket, obj_key, new_obj_key):
    print(f"Copiando objeto a bucket de destino: {obj_key}")
    s3_client.copy_object(
        Bucket=dest_bucket,
        CopySource={'Bucket': source_bucket, 'Key': obj_key},
        Key=new_obj_key
    )

def object_copied(s3_client, dest_bucket, new_obj_key):
    try:
        print(f"Verificando si el objeto ya fue copiado: {new_obj_key}")
        s3_client.head_object(Bucket=dest_bucket, Key=new_obj_key)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

El problema con esta funcion es que solo funciona con la primera carpeta del directorio, copia una carpeta con accountID por su correspondiente nombre y dentro de esa carpeta tampoco copia todo su contenido a su bucket nuevo

Resultado grafico:

[image: Esto mismo ocurre dentro de todas las subcarpetas que haya]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es problema de la funcion lambda o tiene que ver con cuotas de movimiento de archivos de S3?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Las lambdas tienen un tiempo máximo de ejecución. Si se supera ese tiempo la lambda se detiene automáticamente. Mira las gráficas a ver si es que has alcanzado ese tiempo. El timeout lo puedes configurar, pero el máximo son 900 segundos (15 minutos), por lo que si necesitas más tiempo tendrás que preparar el código para que continúe por donde se quedó en la ejecución anterior